# Not all pandas column changing with a created dictionary passed into df.rename()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I created a dictionary to pass into `df.rename()` in order to change some of the column names into something readable. However, only some of the column names change while others stay the same.

I'm learning from a site that has Jupyter notebook integrated into it and also following along using Jupyter notebook on another laptop as a fallback. 
 Everything is fine on the site's Jupyter notebook but something is wrong on my laptop's. I've checked for spelling errors and spacing but everything seems fine.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Record ID': [1,2,3], 'Gender. What is your Gender?': ['M', 'F', 'M']})

dictionary = {'Record ID': 'id', 'Gender. What is your Gender?': 'gender'}

updatedDF = df.rename(dictionary, axis=1)
```

So for example, `Record ID` changes successfully to `id` but `Gender. What is your Gender`? stays the same. It should change to `gender`.

Comment: Welcom to Stackoverflow. In the df your column is named 'Gender. What is your Gender?', but in the rename dictionary the questionmark is missing. If you remove it from your rename dict, it is properly renamed. Likewise if you add the questionmark on the df column name.

Comment: That was a mistake on my part when recreating the problem. The column name does contain a question mark.

Comment: In case you still have renaming problems, maybe you have some funny unicode chars in your name. In such cases you could create a renaming function that uses regex and pass it instead of a dict.

Comment: Hmm I saw, that you updated the text. This version is what I just tested. For my machine it renames the dataframe properly. If you copy that code out again and run it on your machine, and it doesn't work, it would be really strange. Please really copy it out. If it then works while your original code didn't, some part of the string was probably translated. If it still doesn't work it would be very strange.

Comment: The code works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm led to believe the problem is actually a unicode problem and I'm not exactly sure how to fix that.

I came across a solution that bypasses that by just accessing the column name directly instead.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Record ID': [1,2,3], 'Gender. What is your Gender.': ['M', 'F', 'M']})

dictionary = {'Record ID': 'id', df.columns[-1]: 'gender'}

updatedDF = df.rename(dictionary, axis=1)
```